# How to integrate a Google map in my asp.net web page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

In my application I have to integrate a Google map in one of my web pages. Here's my code for integrating the google map:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=3" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 500px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var map = new GMap(document.getElementById("map"));
map.centerAndZoom(new GPoint(-83.022206, 39.998264), 7);
map.setCenter(point, 15);
map.setUIToDefault();
map.setMapType(G_NORMAL_MAP);

// Create the marker and corresponding information window

function createInfoMarker(point, address) {
  var marker = new GMarker(point);
  GEvent.addListener(marker, "click",
    function() {
      marker.openInfoWindowHtml(address);
    }
  );
  return marker;
}

// University Hall
var point = new GPoint(-83.013307, 40.000610);
address = "University Hall<br />230 North Oval Mall <br />Columbus, Ohio 43210";
var marker = createInfoMarker(point, address);
map.addOverlay(marker);

//]]>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's working fine but, here now I want to put my user-defined markers...

Can any one help me in doing this?

Comment: You are specifying v1 of the Google Maps API, that is obsolete.  v2 is deprecated and might stop working as early as May 2013, you should use v3.  The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) for v3 is pretty complete and includes samples.

Comment: @geocodezip The syntax's don't seem to be of v3 but the `v=3` in the script source indicates v3 right?

Comment: @Cdeez: Right! but loading V3 and then using V1 syntax is not going to work. (It's like filling water into your gas tank) ;-)

Comment: haha true. But the OP still said that its working fine.

Comment: Please do some research on the various tutorials available for working with the GMaps API - we'll happily help you with specific problems you encounter on the way there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of Google Maps APIv3 gives sucfficient examples to get an understanding of how to do this-

You can find it here-
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers

Moreover the syntax's you used dont seem to be of V3 so goahead  with the latest version-
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls